# Switch statement inside a foreach loop is failing

Tags: php

I have an array: `$att_arr[] = $attachments`

Output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [has_attachment] => 1
                    [filename] => AWB0091_20170530_26_194710330.pos
                    [name] => AWB0091_20170530_26_194710330.pos
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [has_attachment] => 1
                    [filename] => AWB0091_20170530_35_194511888.pos
                    [name] => AWB0091_20170530_35_194511888.pos
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [has_attachment] => 1
                    [filename] => AWB0091_20170530_22_194511888.neg
                    [name] => AWB0091_20170530_22_194511888.neg
                )
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [has_attachment] => 1
                    [filename] => AWB0091_20170530_45_194052957.neg
                    [name] => AWB0091_20170530_45_194052957.neg
                )
        )
)
```

Now I am trying to use a foreach loop with switch statements to save the details to database but only the first record is inserted and the rest all fails. Here is the code:

```
foreach ($attachments_array as $attachment) {
    if ($attachment['has_attachment'] == 1) {
        $filename = $attachment['name'];
        if (empty($filename)) $filename = $attachment['filename'];
        $extension = pathinfo($filename)['extension'];
        switch ($extension) {
            case strtolower("pos"):
                $posTextFile = $attachment['name']);
                return $this->savePos($posTextFile);
                break;
            case strtolower("neg"):
                $negTextFile = $attachment['name']);
                return $this->saveNeg($negTextFile);
                break;
            default:
                return redirect(url(\Config::get('settings.redirect_path')));
        }
    } else {
        return redirect(url(\Config::get('settings.redirect_path')));
    }
}

private function savePos ($posTextFile) {
    $this->savePosObj->updatePosJob($posTextFile);
    return redirect(url(\Config::get('settings.redirect_path')));

}

private function saveNeg ($negTextFile) {
    $this->savePosObj->updateNegJob($negTextFile);
    return redirect(url(\Config::get('settings.redirect_path')));
}
```

Can anyone please help me out in this regard?

Comment: `is_attachment` != `has_attachment`. I also don't think you're going deep enough down in each array. `var_dump($attachment)` inside your foreach to see if that property even exists.

Comment: What's the point of this ? `code`case strtolower("pos")`code`. I think you want to make the strtolower() over $extension ( and better if you do before the switch ). Using strtolower() over a fixed string ( as strtolower('neg') ) has no point.

Comment: Your code looks very convoluted to me. Extract part of the logic into their own methods, reduce the nesting, reduce the else statements. Do you even know that the switch is your problem on not your loop? Maybe it just runs once and jumped out somewhere you did not expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
$attachment['is_attachment']
```

there is no index called is_attachement, maybe you need to try 
`$attachment['has_attachment']`